# Trying to update version number with batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have two files that I want to update (with the relevant lines shown):

**project.properties**

```
target=android-20
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
android:targetSdkVersion="20"
```

Sometimes I want to change the SDK version (so the number 20 might be something else) in my project, so rather than open two files and edit values all the time I thought maybe I could write a batch script that does this automatically. (seeing I am using Windows)

I've got no idea where to start though. Should I be trying to edit XML attributes in this manner? Could a quick and dirty search and replace work better?

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: What do you want to change? The "20" ?

Comment: As you are obviously able to code in Java: why not run some Java program that reads, parses and replaces ? There are APIs for properties and xml files

Comment: dark fang: yes just change the 20 to another number, like an 18.

Comment: Have your files just one line? If so, then it is simpler to re-create the whole file: `echo target=android-18> project.properties` This is also true for few-lines files.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [replacer.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/replacer.bat)

```
call replacer.bat "project.properties" "target=android-20" "target=android-18"

call replacer.bat "e?AndroidManifest.xml" "android:targetSdkVersion=\u002220\u0022" "android:targetSdkVersion=\u002218\u00222"
```

`е?` is for evaluation for special symbols sequences - like unicode quotes in this case.

you can check also [FindRepl](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697) and [JRepl](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) which are more sophisticated tools